# java generics parameter can't apply to a specific type

Tags: java, generics, casting

```
public class Demo {
    public String work(String s) {
        return s;
    }

    public <T> T Test(T t) {
        // common work to do !!
        // .....
        // spec work to do 
        T result = work(t);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Test() has some common work to do first, then specific work with respect to different type of T. 
The code above causes compiler errors, how can i do this ? 
thanks very much !

Comment: You can't do anything like this in Java.  Decisions about which overload of a method to choose are made at compile time, not runtime.

Comment: how can i achieve ？
 Test() needs to  deal with different param type  and some common work needs to be done first in this function,  i just want to extract the common parts to the Test().

Comment: Pull the common parts out to a separate method, and have multiple overload of test that call that separate method and then do the specialized work.

Comment: this does works. but not in a graceful style.  
it needs to export many interfaces [Test()] to the caller... .
c++ can do this easily, i think java can achieve this too

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Another approach is to use reflection. Do note that reflection is a powerful tool but it comes at a cost (performance.) Perform measurements to see whether this is a viable solution is your specific case:

```
public class Demo {
  private String work(String s) {
    return s.toUpperCase();
  }

  private Boolean work(Boolean b) {
    return !b;
  }

  public <T> T test(T t) {
    // common work to do !!
    // .....

    // Now look-up "work" method for type T. Invoke if defined.
    T result = null;
    try {
      Class<T> tType = (Class<T>) t.getClass();
      Method work = Demo.class.getDeclaredMethod("work", tType);
      if (work.getReturnType() != tType) {
        throw new NoSuchMethodException("No `work` method for type: " + tType);
      }

      result = (T) work.invoke(this, t);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
      // NOOP - or whatever.
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
      // Method invocation failed. Handle properly.
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things that can cause your code not to compile here; aside from the ';', you are returning something from a void method. Kindly post the compiler errors you're facing too, it will make things much clearer to potential responders.

Comment: sorry, this is an simple piece to demonstrate the problem 
The main error is  argument mismatch 
it says:
work()  need parameter like String, but pass a T (generic type)

Answer (score 0):

What you *could* possibly get away with is to create a mapping from type `T` to a ([unary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html)?) [function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html). Then, in the `test` method you can look-up the type `T`. If a function is registerede, apply:

```
public class Demo {
  private static final Map<Class<?>, UnaryOperator<?>> typeFuncs = new HashMap<>();
  static {{
    addTypeFunc(String.class, (String s) -> s); // Anonymous function.
    addTypeFunc(Integer.class, Demo::workInteger); // Function reference.
  }}

  private static <T> void addTypeFunc(Class<T> type, UnaryOperator<T> func) {
    typeFuncs.put(type, func);
  }

  private static Integer workInteger(Integer i) {
    return i;
  }

  public <T> T test(T t) {
    // common work to do !!
    // .....

    T result = null;
    UnaryOperator<T> operator = (UnaryOperator<T>) typeFuncs.get(t.getClass());
    if (operator != null) {
      result = operator.apply(t);
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

Do note that the cast `(UnaryOperator<T>)` in `test` is only safe as we have total control of the relation between key and value types in the `typeFuncs` map.

Comment: thanks very much, this works, but it brings two limitations:
1) need to call addTypeFunc()  manually 
2)  UnaryOperator may not enough  
not gracefull

Comment: @TAW8750 Yes, 1) you need to explicitly map between types and applicable function. 2) What?

Comment: 2) 
UnaryOperator<T> operator = (UnaryOperator<T>) typeFuncs.get(t.getClass());  

here operator maybe complicated, eg: many params